# WebProxy error: Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, networkcredentials, webproxy

I use the following code to obtaing html data from the internet:

```
WebProxy p = new WebProxy("localproxyIP:8080", true);
p.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("domain\\user", "password");
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = p;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
```

But the following error is appeared: "Proxy Authentication Required".
I can't use default proxy because of my code runs from windows service under the special account which there is no default proxy settings for.
So, I want to specidy all proxy settings in my code.
Please advice me how to resolve this error.

Comment: try to remove the domain\\ part (also remember of wrapping `WebClient` with `using()` statement because it implements `IDisposable`)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You've to set the WebClient.Proxy Property..

```
WebProxy p = new WebProxy("localproxyIP:8080", true);
p.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("domain\\user", "password");
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = p;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
**client.Proxy = p;**
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: it's not needed because `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = p` is enough

Comment: you're right if you use WebRequest.Create() and after you call WebRequest.GetResponse(). But in this case he's using the WebClient to make request so the Proxy is not the same.

Comment: Actually `DownloadString` method internally uses `WebRequest` object created by `WebRequest.Create()`. If proxy wasn't particularly set to `WebClient` object, such `WebRequest` object uses proxy obtained from  `WebRequest.InternalDefaultWebProxy` property, which is just set by `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = p` statement;

Comment: Imho solution below https://stackoverflow.com/a/17187136/7225096 is better.

Answer (score 52):

This worked for me:

```
IWebProxy defaultWebProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
defaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
client = new WebClient
    {
        Proxy = defaultWebProxy
    };
string downloadString = client.DownloadString(...);
```

Comment: Wonderful!  This should be part of every WebClient sample.

Comment: Can confirm this answer is perfect - We distributed software to clients that kept hitting this issue due to network restrictions. This patched the single issue everyone was facing. This should be the selected answer. YOU SAVED ME

Comment: I use Console dotnet Core, how can i config it in setting file (such as app.config in Net Framework)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
var transferProxy = new WebProxy("localproxyIP:8080", true);
transferProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
var transferRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
transferRequest.Proxy = transferProxy;
HttpWebResponse transferResponse = 
    (HttpWebResponse)transferRequest.GetResponse(); 
System.IO.Stream outputStream = transferResponse.GetResponseStream();
```